# Is there any way to make the paint created in Texture Paint mode appear in render mode?

Tags: rendering, texturing, texture-painting

I noticed that when I paint anything on my sculpt and then switch to render mode, the paint doesn't show up. I use Cycles as my render engine. Additionally, I can only paint in the solid preview; painting in any other mode doesn't present the paint on the sculpt. Is there any way to make the paint painted in texture paint mode to show up in render mode? Sorry if this question sounds dumb, I am very new to Blender.

[image]

EDIT: So I think I might've figured it out. I did a test paint on the object and went to the shading workspace. I added the image texture node and played around with the connection things, and I found out that connecting the color under the image texture node to base color under the other node, it makes the texture paint appear in the final render.

Comment: if you are in Eevee you should see the painting in Render mode as well, but maybe you've chosen the bad texture image in the texture slots in the N panel?

Comment: Oh, I use Cycles as my render engine; using Eevee creates these weird visual glitches whereas Cycles has none for me. I’m guessing the render engines makes a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what the glitches are caused by, but is your problem fixed in Eevee? If not, check the Texture Slots

Comment: In Cycles it looks like if you are in Render mode and paint you won't directly see the result, you need to switch to another mode then switch back, if it still doesn't work you need to check your nodes or the image selected in the Texture Slots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Texture paint is supposed to affect render mode. There is a good chance that the image you are painting onto is not connected to the material assigned to that area on the object (*the* material if you only have one on the object). Check for this in the shader editor. If you see no image texture node, add one and select the image data block you were painting onto.

Tip: click the image pull down icon on the image texture node, not the wider “Open file” button” right next to it. You want to pick an image that is already loaded into blender: an existing image data block.

Comment: I added the image texture node and add the image I am painting on, but I feel like I'm missing another step. The paint created on the image still doesn't show up in rendered mode. Is there anything I'm supposed to connect within the nodes?

Comment: @LailaB add a screenshot of the node setup?

Comment: I updated the post with the setup, and I think I might've figured it out after following your solution. I just had to play around with the node connections. Thank you for the help!